# filter cards using button and search box Angular 8

Tags: angular

I have list of cards which i filter them with a search box using a pipe:

```
export class OrderbyPipe implements PipeTransform{
transform(array: any, sortBy: string, order: string): any[] {
    const sortOrder = order ? order : String; // setting default ascending order   
     return orderBy(array, [sortBy], [sortOrder]);
     }
```

in my search im doing like this in Html:

```
<mat-card   *ngFor="let s of rslt | sortTurbine:searchTerm">
```

its working fine,now the problem is i have 3 different buttons, each of them represents a status in my list(RUN,STOP,ERROR),when the button clicked the cards should be sorted based on the mentioned status,

```
<button (click)="filterCards(status)">
```

in my component i have implemented filterCards function:

```
            filterTurbines(status){
        
        return rslt.filter(tur=>tur.turStat===status);

        }
```

when i click the RUN stat button,it filters the list(rslt) and shows cards with RUN status,but after the rslt filtered i dont have access to my main list ,the first rslt list,so i cant filter it anymore

Answer (score 0):

You should store two arrays, a general array with all the data not filtered and a second one with the filtered data. At the beginning, you set the filtered data to contain all the data and in the html template you loop through the filtered data. Then, in your filter function, you update the filtered data by filtering through the general array.

It will look something like this:

```
export class YourComponent {
    allRslt = [];
    filteredRslt = [];

    ...
    
    ngOnInit() {
       // initialize the variables
       this.allRslt = ...;
       this.filteredRslt = this.allRslt;
    }

    filter(status) {
        this.filteredRslt = this.allRslt.filter(tur => tur.turStat === status);
    }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let s of filteredRslt | sortTurbine:searchTerm">
```

Comment: you need use the spread operator to make a copy of the array, else the array will be the same (you simple declare two name of variables that make reference to the same array: `this.filteredRstl=[...this.allRstl]`

Comment: @Eliseo whats the diffrence between this.filterRslt=this.allRslt and  this.filterRslt=[...this.allRslt ]

Comment: In one case you has an **unique array** and two variables that make refererence to the array, and in the second case you has two arrays. In the fisrt case `this.filterRslt.push('one'); console(this.allRst)` return the array with the 'one' element. (it's the same array!). In the second case are differents arrays, you only add the 'one' to filterRslt